# Is it possible to use D3 word cloud on your (for profit) website for free?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, word-cloud

I am trying to create a website using React, and I need to implement a word cloud.

Is the [D3 word cloud](https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud) free? I have read the [LICENSE](https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud/blob/master/LICENSE) file, and it says it is protected by copyright (doesn't sound open source to me). I am not sure I fully understood all the terms, I am looking for more detailed information about how they will translate into practice.

Can you create a website and (eventually) make money with it using that tool for free?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you have a question about [tag:licensing] but the tag wiki for that tag says: Questions about using software licenses are off-topic, but may be asked at opensource.stackexchange.com or law.stackexchange.com

Comment: "it is protected by copyright (doesn't sound open source to me)" — Open Source is very explicitly not the same as Public Domain.